# Cant get "Draggable" to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I came across this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/efvsbxL7/1/) and it works almost similar as something I need so I decided to copy it and adjust it for my project.

There is only one slight problem and that is that I cant get this example to work on my local machine.

Updated:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/‌​jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default big">Activiteiten</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Zelfscan</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Samenwerken</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default big">Doelen en expertises</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Opleidingen</li>
</ul>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
            $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
            $("#sortable .big").css("width","210px");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS part is working, the javascript isnt. It is kinda the first time that im using this so I apologize if I made a stupid mistake.

Kind regards,

job

Comment: You forgot to include jquery. Link for you `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You are missing the jquery.js lib

Comment: And there is no need for both `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat alright, and this needs to be on top with the stylesheet or at the <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript"> part?

Comment: Alright got it at the script part and removed the min but still doesnt work

The code in the main post is updated to what I have now

Comment: @AniketSahrawat hmm I added your link instead of the jquery-ui.js (see edited main post) but it still doesnt work

Comment: Sorry the link i posted was wrong...Sorry my bad...I will be back in a moment with the answer.

Comment: Replace the jquery links with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`. This must work now

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yea cool. it works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include Jquery Library before

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```